# Search a variable for an address

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to match information stored in a variable. I have a list of uuid's and ip addresses beside them. The code I have is:

```
r = re.compile(r'urn:uuid:5EEF382F-JSQ9-3c45-D5E0-K15X8M8K76')

m = r.match(str(serv))
if m1:
    print'Found'
```

The string serv contains is:

```
urn:uuid:7FDS890A-KD9E-3h53-G7E8-BHJSD6789D:[u'http://10.10.10.20:12365/7FDS890A-KD9E-3h53-G7E8-BHJSD6789D/']
---------------------------------------------
urn:uuid:5EEF382F-JSQ9-3c45-D5E0-K15X8M8K76:[u'http://10.10.10.10:42365']
---------------------------------------------
urn:uuid:8DSGF89S-FS90-5c87-K3DF-SDFU890US9:[u'http://10.10.10.40:5234']
---------------------------------------------
```

So basically I am wanting to find the uuid string and find out what it's address is and store it as a variable. So far I have just tried to get it to match the string to no avail. Can anyone point out a solution to this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your regex is very simple, so much so that there's no need to use regular expression at all.

```
>>> serv="""
... urn:uuid:7FDS890A-KD9E-3h53-G7E8-BHJSD6789D:[u'http://10.10.10.20:12365/7FDS890A-KD9E-3h53-G7E8-BHJSD6789D/']
... ---------------------------------------------
... urn:uuid:5EEF382F-JSQ9-3c45-D5E0-K15X8M8K76:[u'http://10.10.10.10:42365']
... ---------------------------------------------
... urn:uuid:8DSGF89S-FS90-5c87-K3DF-SDFU890US9:[u'http://10.10.10.40:5234']
... ---------------------------------------------
... """
>>> tomatch="urn:uuid:5EEF382F-JSQ9-3c45-D5E0-K15X8M8K76"
>>> for row in serv.split("\n"):
...  if tomatch in row:
...   print row[ row.find("[")+1 : ].replace("]","")
...
u'http://10.10.10.10:42365'
```

Comment: @ghostdog -- Thanks for the response - I tried this but it doesn't find anything. It can't find a match. It happened with the answer from Marcelo as well which is strange. Can you think why this is? Could it be with the way the variable is created? Thanks

Comment: try the way i do it with the interpreter.

Comment: @ghostdog -- The variable was not being output as a string properly. But your answer had some of the code that I found useful, regular expression wasn't required. thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
r = re.compile(r"urn:uuid:5EEF382F-JSQ9-3c45-D5E0-K15X8M8K76:\[u'(.*)'\]")
m = r.search(str(serv))
if m:
    print 'Found', m.group(1)
```

Comment: @Marcelo Cantos -- Thanks for the response - I tried this but it doesn't find anything. It can't find a match. It happened with the answer from ghostdog as well which is strange. Can you think why this is? Could it be with the way the variable is created? Thanks